# compress dir to same size split files，depressed files individual？

Tags: linux

I need to transfer a 1G folder over the network, and the data formats I send and receive are all under my control. In order to speed up the reception of data, I do this now:

1. Before transferring, compress the 1G folder and then transfer it.
2. after download all，decompress it.

It can reduce some time because the amount of data transferred becomes smaller, but it also requires time for decompression. Is it possible to compress a folder into many files of the same size, download one file and decompress one file, and when all files are decompressed, it will be the initial folder？ my question is:

1. Can this be achieved?
2. How can I uncompressing file while downloading it?
3. how to reduce the download and uncompress time？

Comment: [man rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: `rsync -z` does this automatically. Another common trick is to do `tar cz mydir | ssh yourhost tar xzv` which will also compress and decompress on the fly

Comment: The transmission channel is uncontrollable. I can only send one packet to the transmission channel for transmission

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. What does "send one packet to the transmission channel" mean? You mean send one file only? And what is this "transmission channel" that you refer to? An IP network?

Comment: yes ，just send one file only. the transmission channel is an doip network，client read 1K bytes at a time and then transmit， server receive the 1K data and call the callback function. I can do something in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose original folder is in the HOME directory. Make a tar archive of the 1G folder using a commands like,

   cd;
   mkdir tmp;
   tar -cvzf tmp/original-folder.tar.gz original-folder
2. Split the tar archive into small files like, xaa, xab, ..., using the split command, e.g.,

   split --bytes=100000000 original-folder.tar.gz
3. Join the pieces at the destination with the cat command,

   cat xaa xab xac [...] > transferred-folder.tar.gz
4. Untar to get the folder

   tar -xvzf transferred-folder.tar.gz

Comment: before do the step 3，need sure that all the files have been transferred，it does not reduce the decompress time，if where is any way to download a package and decompress a package, when all the packages are downloaded, almost all package decompress?